# Click Once through Development / Test / Production deployment

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I am wondering if anyone has experience of managing a Click Once application through a Development > Testing > Production deployment cycle?

My application uses a WCF Service to get its data. The service exists on the three different stages as well so the deployment will need to point to the different services at each stage.

I initially thought that TFS & Release Management could do the job but when looking into the details I found it impossible to use Release Management for Click Once in this way.

Maybe I am looking at things with Release Management in the wrong way - but as I understand it, the project is built before it gets to Release Management, by which time it is very difficult and convoluted to change the Web Service details for each stage.

I then started writing an application to manage the deployment - I get the files for a selected TFS Changeset, update the bits I need to for each stage and initiate a deploy. I am starting to think that this is a bit messy and cant help but think that if a client has all three versions of the client installed (Dev/Test/Production) that there are still shared resources between the installations that make this impossible.

Surely there must be a fairly easy... standard way of deploying Click Once across three different environments of deployment?!